# Cannot install D3 7 on Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, d3.js

I am trying multiple methods for installing `d3` and `d3-sankey` on a Rails 6.1.5 app, but with the exception of a direct link to d3js.org, nothing is working yet.

I have a working example that gets its JS with the following scripts at the top:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-sankey@0.12.3/dist/d3-sankey.min.js"></script>
```

#### Attempt 1: d3-rails gem

https://github.com/iblue/d3-rails

```
# Gemfile with bundle install
d3-rails

# /app/javascripts/packs AND/OR /app/assets/javascripts/ with server restart
# //= require d3
# //= require d3-sankey
```

With the above, the chart does not display. The JS console cannot find d3.

#### Attempt 2: d3 and d3-sankey via yarn

```
# Add d3 and d3-sankey
yarn add d3 d3-sankey

# Confirm d3 and d3-sankey are in yarn.lock

# /app/javascripts/packs AND/OR /app/assets/javascripts/ with server restart
# //= require d3
# //= require d3-sankey
```

With the above, d3 is still not found.

#### Attempt 3: Based on https://github.com/rossta/rails6-webpacker-demo/tree/example/d3

Beyond the above, create d3.js and refer to it in application.js:

```
# d3.js
import * as d3 from "d3";
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  d3.selectAll("div").append("p").text("Hello, World!");
});
// Only necessary if you wish to export d3 to global scope
window.d3 = d3;

# application.js
import "../javascripts/d3"
```

With the above and server restart, d3 is not found.

How can I load d3 and d3-sankey?